# Sharing printer with wifi modem windows 7

Tags: wireless-networking

I have an internet broad band connection from bsnl , and three PC( all Windows 7), I can use internet on all over the three computer, via connecting to wifi modem provided by BSNL.

I have one printer(it does not have Wi-Fi, or LAN, it has only one USB port )and want to share this printer on all three PC.

or this I made a Wi-Fi ad hoc connection in PC1( one with printer connected) named PC1 and connect to this network, and search on other PC. And after finding the PC1, I connect to my PC2 , and goes in network and add printer , and then browse the printer shared on PC1. And I can print from PC2.

But main problem is that when I connect my computer to PC1 network(for printing job) , my Wi-Fi internet connection gets disconnected and I cannot use internet. And vise versa. And every time when I restart PC i have to find the printer on the network.I

So please help me out that how can i share my printer to other two pc. And  use internet also. I don't want to use LANconnection.

P.s. 
Can i use my wifi broadband modem for sharing printer.? So that i can use internet with sharing printer.

Comment: What are the IP addresses of the 3 PCs?

Answer (score 0):

There are Wifi routers that you can connect a USB printer to. Google *Wifi router usb printer*

Another option would be to get a Wifi enabled printserver, such as this one here: http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WPS510U, or, if your router has a free ethernet port available, there are wired usb printservers as well. Using one of these, PC1 doesn't even have to be on to be able to print from other machines.

Comment: Most GDI (i.e. low cost) printers do not like being USB connected to a router or printserver. If the printer supports a printer language (PCL5/6 - not PCL3, PostScript) it should work; otherwise, beware!

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: so ultimately do i have to buy some stuff..?

Comment: If all pc's are connected to the same wifi router, can't you just share the printer in the usual way? E.g. go to \\pc1\printers\yoursharedprinter

Comment: I tried this but , could not find printer

Comment: Your router may have client isolation enabled, this is a security measure that disables communication between connected devices. Just to be sure, could you try to use the IP address rather than the actual device name, \\a.b.c.d\your_share